# ¿Como obtener la cantidad de dias, horas y minutos transcurridos a partir de una fecha? en C#

Tags: c#, date, datetime

he tratado de obtener los días, horas y minutos de una fecha a partir de esto:

```
DateTime fecha_actual= "26-07-2017 18:45";
DateTime fecha_ingreso= "25-07-2017 16:45";
TimeSpan ts = fecha_actual - fecha_ingreso
int differenceInDias = ts.Days;
int differenceInHours = ts.Hours;
int differenceInMinuntos = ts.Minutes;
```

La idea que obtenga las horas transcurridas(26 horas) desde las 16 horas del dia 25, hasta la hora de la fecha_actual, lo mismo en minutos y horas.

Comment: Con el código que muestras, ¿te marca algún error? ¿Los resultados no son los correctos?

Comment: me muestra valores que no corresponde, por ejemplo en hora, me da valor 1.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Utiliza [`TotalHours`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timespan.totalhours(v=vs.110).aspx) que te da el total de horas del `TimeSpan`:

```
DateTime fecha_actual= new DateTime(day:26, month: 7, year: 2017, hour:18, minute:45, second: 0);
        DateTime fecha_ingreso= new DateTime(day:25, month: 7, year: 2017, hour:16, minute:45, second: 0);
        TimeSpan ts = fecha_actual - fecha_ingreso;

        var differenceInDias = ts.TotalDays;
        var differenceInHours = ts.TotalHours;
        var differenceInMinuntos = ts.TotalMinutes;
        Console.WriteLine(differenceInHours); // 26
```

[Ejemplo en .Net Fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/ZRZEHy)

Comment: excelente, era justo lo que necesitaba.

Comment: @Einer Cómo hago para que en vez de añadir eso de "day:26, month: 7, year: 2017, hour:18, minute:45, second: 0",yo ponga lo que esta dentro de un textbox.?